# Finding mid-point of $BC$ if point $A$, orthocenter and circumcenter are given in a triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry

> If in a triangle $ABC$, $A \equiv (1,10)$, circumcenter $\equiv (-\frac13, \frac23)$ and orthocenter $\equiv (\frac{11}3, \frac43)$ then the coordinates of mid-point of side opposite to A is?

[image]

Here clearly point $Q$ is circumcenter and point $P$ is orthocenter. The only thing I see here is $AP ||DQ$. So their slopes are same. So we can get an equation using this. But how am I supposed to get another equation?

Any other way of solving this problem would also be appreciated.

Comment: With orthocenter P and circumcenter Q and with D the mid-point of BC we also have |AP|=2|DQ|.

Comment: @user254665 why is that?

Comment: From the properties of the Euler line of the triangle and the Feuerbach circle (also called the Euler-Feuerbach circle, the 9-point circle,and other names) which is the circumcircle of the mid-points of the sides.  To answer in detail would be an essay.

Comment: @user254665 thanks for the help and the comment at the correct moment. I had actually asked Lucian to explain the reason behind it...:p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $~$ You were given the orthocenter *H* and the circumcenter *O*. But what were you **not**

given ? The centroid *G*. Now, do you, by any chance, know that the latter is found on the

segment uniting the former two, and, not only that, but it divides said segment in a ratio of

$1:2$ ? $($Remember that the centroid also divides each median into the same ratio as well$).$

In other words, $G\in(OH)$ and $GH=2GO.~$ At the same time, $G=\dfrac{A+B+C}3,~$ and

$M=\dfrac{B+C}2.$

Comment: @manshu: I am not personally aware of any particularly elegant way of proving it, but, if you are familiar with analytic geometry, then, given enough time and patience, it should be trivial.